# Best SEO practices for for multi-page articles

Tags: seo, content, tags

I'm planning on releasing a number of articles spanning multiple pages. Each page of the article is thematically connected to the other pages through its main topic, but focuses on a particular aspect of this topic. For example, an article on the human body, could have pages focused on the skeleton, the muscles, the vascular system, the nervous system...

Each page would have different title & h1 tags and hence different KWs in the URL.

What is the best SEO practice to tell Google that these pages are all part of the same article (and that, somehow, belong together)?

Note: there are no restrictions as to how the URL or the pages should be built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas for sending a signal to Google that the pages are related and belong together:

- **Use a hierarchical page structure.** For instance, `/human-body/`, `/human-body/skeleton/`, `/human-body/muscles/`, etc. The `/human-body/` page should contain an introduction, summary, and/or table of contents.
- **Use breadcrumbs on each page.** At the top of each page, use a navigation structure that looks similar to `Articles -> Human Body -> Skeleton`, where each is a clickable link. This provides convenient navigation for the user while helping reinforce the SEO signal sent by the URL hierarchy.
- **Use previous/next navigation.** This allows the user to navigate each page in the article one by one, and further signals to Google that they are part of a series.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Maximillian's good advice, Google has made, for this specific purpose, the link rel next & previous tags - https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev

Answer (score 1):

This is what we call Creating a **Topical Authority** by making a clear and clean SilO Structure around any NICHE.

And it is actually the best way to build authority in your niche.

As per my experience, you need to publish a well-researched and in-depth article on the main Keyword which can be your money Keyword/Page.

The rest of the topics have separate articles and you need to interlink them with the main money page.

If you have a static homepage then it can be your money page and you will interlink it with all other blog posts. This gives more power to the homepage.

As per the example you have given the main money page will be "human body" and all the other parts of the human body will support in terms of Interlinks to the Human Body. So the human body will be stronger and authoritative.